# How to hide short product description from Catalog page

Tags: magento2

I want to display short description in Product detail page.

But want to hide short description in Product list page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Catalog Page or Block and add css

```
<style>
.short_des_class_name{
    display:none
}
</style>
```

*NOTE:* Add this css in catalog page only not in style.css

Comment: Working like charm @Arun Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> You remove it in layout xml.
> Make the file
> `{theme_dir}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

***Note:- after flush magento cache.***